# getaddrinfo error: ai_socktype not supported

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, getaddrinfo

```
struct addrinfo *myAddrinfo, *curMyAddrinfo, hint;
memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hint.ai_family = AF_INET;
hint.ai_protocol = AI_PASSIVE;
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

const int code = getaddrinfo(NULL, SERVER_PORT, &hint, &myAddrinfo);
if ((code) != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo error occours: %s ",
            gai_strerror(code));
    return 1;
}
```

this gives the error: "ai_socktype not supported"
if i comment out the `hint.ai_protocol = AI_PASSIVE;` it will get through, but i am wondering why it happens?

thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because AI_PASSIVE is referred to ai_flags field, (not ai_protocol).
Try :

```
hint.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
```

And have a look at [addrinfo structure](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getaddrinfoman.html).

Answer (score 10):

It's worth just adding here, as this is the top result when searching for "ai_socktype not supported"
an alternative reason for it could be that hints is not zeroed on the stack;
for that you need

```
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
```

Nissan's code of course did have that already

Comment: What the sentence `Nissan's code of course did have that already` does mean?